# Spring,Beanの取得について

Tags: java, spring

Springを学習中です。
本のサンプルコードを少し変えてみたのですが
NullPointerExceptionになってしまいます。

```
public class ProductSampleRun {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ProductSampleRun productSampleRun = new ProductSampleRun();
        productSampleRun.execute();
    }

    public void execute(){

        //BeanFactory ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        //      "/spring/application-config.xml");
        //ProductService productService = ctx.getBean(ProductService.class);

        productService.addProduct(new Product("ホチキス",100));

        Product product = productService.findByProductName("ホチキス");
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

付随情報として
`ProductServiceImple`が`@Component`として登録されています。
web.xmlに`ContextConfigLocation`と`ContextLoaderListener`を記述しています。
application-configに`Component-Scan`を記述しています。

Springがまだ全然わかっていないのですが、Beanを取得する場合
必ず`getBean`をしなければいけないのでしょうか?(コメント部)
`@Autowired`でいけると思ったのですが・・。

Answer (score 1):

SpringMVCでWebプロジェクトだと`@Autowired`や`@Resource`で行けるはずだが。

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ProductSampleRun productSampleRun = new ProductSampleRun();
    productSampleRun.execute();
}
```

だとProductSampleRunオブジェクトはSpringで管理されていないから、Autowiredが動かなかった。

```
String[] xmlCfg = new String[] {"classpath:/spring/applicationContext-service.xml",
            "classpath:/spring/applicationContext-util.xml",
            "classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml"}; 
ApplicationContext context  = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(xmlCfg);
// 获取inspectionUtil bean
ProductSampleRun productSample = (ProductSampleRun) context.getBean(ProductSampleRun.class);
```

のようにApplicationContext を利用してBeanを取得してみてください。